# Pipe character on location header doesn't work

Tags: php, header, location, pipe

I´m trying to redirect URL using this:

$url = "Location: http://mydomain.com/#!Mypage|000";
header ($url);

But the result is a redirection to :

http://mydomain.com/#!Mypage%7C000

The problem is the pipe char. How is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

`%7C` *is* the pipe char.  If the web server at mydomain.com treats `Mypage%7C000` any differently than `Mypage|000`, then the web server is broken.

Comment: If i type on webbrowser:   http://mydomain.com/#!Mypage|000   The server understands correctly... i think the server is not broken. Any other solution?

Comment: If you type on webbrowser mydomain.com/#!Mypage%7C000 the server should do the same thing.  If it doesn't, the server is broken.